# Flask: app.debug produces traceback

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

I am trying to set up a flask app, this is the simplest rendition of the code.

**fm/__init__.py**

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

Now when I try to run it on the console:

```
>>> import fm
>>> fm.app.run()
 Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 Restarting with reloader
/Users/myname/Documents/app/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

Whether or not I run it in a virtual environment, the error is still the same. If I remove the debug flag, the server starts. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wondering, I discovered the problem. The debug mode won't work if called from the **init** file. So using [this model](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/) I created a file in the directory above with the following:

**run.py**

```
from fm import app
app.run(debug=True)
```